# change toast message using switch

Tags: java, android, android-toast

Is there any way I can change the toast message based on the xml id of the button that clicks it?

```
public void toast (View view) {
    String toast ="";
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case findViewById(R.id.spotify): toast = "Spotify streamer will show here";
            break;
        case findViewById(R.id.scores):  toast = "Scores app will show here";
            break;
        case findViewById(R.id.library):  toast = "March";
            break;
        case findViewById(R.id.build):  toast = "Build app will show here";
            break;
        case findViewById(R.id.xyz):  toast = "XYZ Reader app will show here";
            break;
        case findViewById(R.id.capstone):  toast = "My Capstone app will show here";
            break;
        Toast.makeText(this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove `findViewById` from there and just have `case R.id.spotify:` and etc. and it will work as you expect.

Comment: It says that the Toast.makeText line is not reachable :/ It also says that the toast strings are never used. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Yeah, put that line outside of the switch statement.

Comment: Thanks!!! First time actually using a switch...beginners mistake :D

Answer (score 4):

just use `case R.id.spotify:` instead of `case findViewById(R.id.spotify):` etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
public void toast (View view) {
String toast ="";
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.spotify: toast = "Spotify streamer will show here";
        break;
    case R.id.scores:  toast = "Scores app will show here";
        break;
    case R.id.library:  toast = "March";
        break;
    case R.id.build:  toast = "Build app will show here";
        break;
    case R.id.xyz:  toast = "XYZ Reader app will show here";
        break;
    case R.id.capstone:  toast = "My Capstone app will show here";
        break;
   }
   Toast.makeText(this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: It says that the Toast.makeText line is not reachable :/ It also says that the toast strings are never used. Can you help me fix this?